# What is the keycode for ios keyboard arrow buttons

Tags: javascript, ios, keyboard-events, keycode

[image: IOS]

I need to capture the keycode for the highlighted arrow buttons in iphone keyboard.What will be the key code for this ? I am thinking it will be tab key which is 9.Any confirmation will be helpful.

Comment: Have you tested this using [`.key` or `.code`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code)? You could also use `blur` or `focus` events, because that is what these keys will actually do anyway.

Comment: You want to do this in JavaScript instead of native iOS app, right? Be sure to note that user is able to install custom keyboards, which may yield different results.